# $H^+\to L^-$ and $H^-\to L^+$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Define

$H^{+}=\{z:y>0\}$

$H^{-}=\{z:y<0\}$

$L^{+}=\{z:x>0\}$

$L^{-}=\{z:x<0\}$

$f(z)=\frac{2z+1}{5z+3}$  maps

$1.$ $H^+\to H^+$ and $H^-\to H^-$

$2$. $H^+\to H^-$ and $H^-\to H^+$

$3.$ $H^+\to L^-$ and $H^-\to L^+$

$4.$ $H^+\to L^+$ and $H^-\to L^-$

here  $\to$ means "onto", well, I have no idea how to solve this one. please help.
$X$ axis is mapped to the curve ${2x+1\over 5x+3}$

Comment: What does $i$ map to?

Comment: ${1\over 12}-{i\over 4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the coefficients of this Möbius transformation are real, it maps $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself, hence the upper and lower half plane are either mapped to themselves or swapped.
This rules out 3. and 4., whereas one of 1., 2. must be true.
Computing the value at any point in $H_+$ and checking whether it is in $H_+$ or $H_-$ the settle the matter. As $H_+\ni i\mapsto \frac1{12}-\frac i4\in H_-$, answer 2. must be correct.

Answer (score 0):

if $F(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and $ad-bc=1$ then upper and lower half plane are  mapped to themselves only

Comment: You should expand your answer a little, explain at least in outline why this as you say. Also, you should add some capitalization and punctuation. On some forums I write in all lowercase, but here it is customary to use proper English. Also, you should enclose your math formulas in dollar signs.